# When is the wp-settings-[time] cookie generated?

Tags: customization, cookies, user-interface

I created a custom plugin for login and registration forms.
When I log in for a new user, 4 cookies are set : `PHPSESSID`, `wordpress_test_cookie`, `wordpress_logged_in_`, and 2 `wordpress_sec_` .

But I don't have `wp-settings-` and `wp-settings-time-`. However my admin account has these cookies.

I can't find a wordpress documentation that explain which function set these cookies.
It is just said :

Without plugins installed, WordPress sets the following cookies:

- `wordpress_[hash]`
- `wordpress_logged_in_[hash]`
- `wordpress_test_cookie`
- `wp-settings-{time}-[UID]`

I don't use "setcookie" at the moment .

The functions I use to allow him to access his account :

```
wp_clear_auth_cookie();
wp_set_current_user($info->ID, $username);  
wp_set_auth_cookie( $info->ID, true, is_ssl() );
```

Comment: Searching for `wp-settings-time-` I found the following occurences: wp-includes/js/utils.min.js line 2, wp-includes/js/utils.js line 188, wp-includes/pluggable.php line 1029, wp-includes/option.php lines 1039 & 1052. Have you checked these files to see when the code is triggered?

Comment: Is there a problem you are trying to solve that has lead you to this that you believe is caused by the lack of these 2 cookies?

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I found the function corresponding `wp_user_settings()`.